# Best practice to create .NET Web API using generated Server Stub

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

b) After generating the .NET C# server stub, the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#ignore-file-format) is not very verbose about how to use it:

> You need to implement the logic yourself to handle whatever work the
>   API needs to do. Once the implementation is ready, you can deploy the
>   API locally or on your server. See the README.md file in the
>   downloaded archive to get started.

Is there any tutorial about how to use the code? I would like to use inheritance to avoid code changes of the generated code. But the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#ignore-file-format) talks about just ignoring some generated files. The swagger support told me to just "migrate" the changes on every change. What is possible, but I hoped to be able to leave generated files untouched. Am I wrong here, is there no parctical need for this? I would like to use the server stub in a continuous integration environment.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to customize the templates.

1. Clone the [swagger-codegen repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen).
2. Assuming you are using the latest stable v2 version of the code generation tool, then master branch is fine. Otherwise checkout the tag for the tool version you are using.
3. In Windows Explorer, open `swagger-codegen\modules\swagger-codegen\src\main\resources`\ and copy the `aspnetcore` directory. Paste that into your customer source code repository.
4. When next you run the codegen tool, provide the `-t` argument:

   ```
   java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate
       -i <your Open API spec URL/file> 
       -l aspnetcore
       -o <outputdir> 
       -t <relative path to your>\aspnetcore
       ... other args as needed
   ```

Now you can modify those templates with custom code. For example, you could have an external library with a new base controller class that provides some generic business logic. Then you could modify the `controller.mustache` file to reference your base class. Just one of many examples. Add your custom templates to your source control for continuous integration.

Caveats: There is a `controller.mustache` file directly in `aspnetcore` and another in `aspnetcore\2.1`. In studying the [source code](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AspNetCoreServerCodegen.java), I see that the 2.1 folder is used for any version of ASP.NET Core *other than 2.0*. I'm new to this tool myself and have not fully figured out how to exploit it; the utility generates source code that will not build for me out of the box. It does not generate the security classes, but it does generate code that tries to *use* those security classes. Thus I'm having to comment out the security code in the templates.